# Counting the frequency in 100 arrays, want the 6 most frequent numbers to be displayed

Tags: php, arrays, frequency

I would like to display the 6 most frequent numbers out of 100 the arrays to be displayed, so far I have this:

```
foreach($lottoTickets as $i =>$ivalue)
{

        $counts = array_count_values($tickets);
        arsort($counts);
        $list = array_keys($counts);
        var_dump($list);
}
```

But this shows the frequency for the seperate arrays, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will fetch the 6 most frequent elements among 100 arrays:

```
$freqArr = array();
foreach($allArrays as $array) {
   foreach($array as $num) {
      if(isset($freqArr[$num])) {
         $freqArr[$num] += 1;
      } else {
         $freqArr[$num] = 1;
      }
   }
}

arsort($freqArr);
$counts = array_slice($freqArr, 0, 5);
$list = array_keys($counts);
var_dump($list);
```